# (Doctrine) Join from child to parent where parent has n relationships to child

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I currently have an entity structure like so;

```
ParentEntity
  - id
  - name 
  - childEntityRelation1
  - childEntityRelation2
  - childEntityRelation3
  - childEntityRelation4

ChildEntity
  - id
  - ...
```

where ParentEntity has four mandatory relationships to separate instances of ChildEntity, which works fine. ChildEntity however does not have any knowledge of ParentEntity.

How can I, for any given ChildEntity whilst using the QueryBuilder, return its corresponding parent entity? Does ChildEntity need four separate inverse relations to the ParentEntity, and if so how does that work in a query?

---

**Entity Mappings**

Each of the four child relations on the parent entity are as follows;

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ChildEntity", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="child_one_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
```

With ChildEntity currently having no annotated relation to its parent.

Comment: Please add your current associations mappings.

Comment: Added an example of a child entity relation, all four are the same but with different join columns @xyoTick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you reverse your relations, so that childrens have ManyToOne relations instead of parent? It'll be much simpler if you define this relation like this:

ParentEntity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ChildEntity", mappedBy="parent")
 */
private $children
```

ChildEntity:

```
/** 
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="ParentEntity", inversedBy="children")
 * @JoinColumn(name="id_parent", referencedColumnName="id")  
 */
private $parent
```

Comment: Thanks - Yes but I then lose the easier differentiation between the different children (each parent must have 4 children, and each one has a different meaning from a domain perspective). That's why I originally had them as separate relations (so I can do something like `$parent->getChild1()`, `$parent->getChild2()` etc

Answer (score 0):

In the repository of parent entity you could do something like this

```
$qb=$this->createQueryBuilder('p');
$e=$qb->expr();
return $qb->andWhere( $e->orX('p.childEntityRelation1=:child', 'p.childEntityRelation2=:child', 'p.childEntityRelation3=:child', 'p.childEntityRelation4=:child' ))
->setParameter('child', $childEntity)
->getQuery()->getResult()
```